# How to configure routes for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I want the `users#show` action to be available under the attribute username instead of the user_id.

So if I go to a user, I want the url to show something like `users/some_username` instead of `users/22`

My Routes:

```
resources :users, only: %i(show edit update) do
      member do
        get :follows
        get :statistic
        get :my_topics, path: :topics
      end
    end
```

Comment: You can replace `locolhost/users` with `locolhost/username` but it is impossible to replace member route to collection route. Perhaps, you can do  `locolhost/users/22` with `locolhost/username/22`

Comment: btw: Don't get discouraged by the downvotes, your question was not quite clear, that's why I edited the question, keep it up, but you could try to work on the language of the question a bit more! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `param` option to the routes.

```
resources :users, param: :name, only: %i(show edit update) do
  member do
    get :follows
    get :statistic
    get :my_topics, path: :topics
  end
end
```

Using `rake routes | grep user` will result in the following.

```
  follows_user GET      /users/:name/follows(.:format)     users#follows
statistic_user GET      /users/:name/statistic(.:format)   users#statistics
my_topics_user GET      /users/:name/topics(.:format)      users#my_topics
     edit_user GET      /users/:name/edit(.:format)        users#edit
          user GET      /users/:name(.:format)             users#show
               PATCH    /users/:name(.:format)             users#update
               PUT      /users/:name(.:format)             users#update
```

Comment: Can you provide routes defined by `rake routes | grep user` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend on nice the answer from Robert: Another way would be to use a gem that is dedicated to do exactly this. One of the many options could be https://github.com/norman/friendly_id.

The gist of it is that you add a field to your user model (here, `slug`, that holds the url segment) which you generate in your model. For fetching records, a method is used that takes either the id as before, or the slug.

In your case, this might be an overkill unless you consider to have the same url requirement for other routes and models.

Side note: I have no affiliation with this project, I just used it a few times before.